# QGLWidget as viewport of QGraphicsView on Android display random pixels randomly

Tags: android, qt, qglwidget

I wrote a game using Qt GraphcisView Framework for Android.

Currently, I use:

- Qt 5.7.1
- Android SDK 28(Android 9.0)
- Android NDK r14b

to build the final apk.

By using QGLWidget, I can see better performance(higher FPS) than using QOpenGLWidget, but sometimes get strange layer of random color pixels over my game scene.

I don't know how this happens, and I've tried many newer version of Qt and Android SDK/NDK, problem remains.

How to solve this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but looks like you platform doesn't support OpenGL graphics, take a look on [OpenGL ES](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl).

Comment: Thanks, but everything works fine except for this random behavior, the game under the transparent layer is not affected. I guess it's a QGLWidget bug on Android.